# Detect when the touch event is over in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I detect when the touch event is over in Android,in Webviews specifically.

pseudocode:
if (touch event is over) then
do something
end

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend adding real code instead of pseudocode. It's hard to provide help otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MotionEvent` object passed to the `onTouchEvent(...)` method has a [getAction()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction()) method, you can use it to determine if the event is over. eg:

```
webViews.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //pointer down.
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    //event has finished, pointer is up or event was canceled or the pointer is outside of the view's bounds
                    break;
            }
            return false;
      }
}
```

Also, if you want to consume the event (stop it from propagating) just make the `onTouch(...)` method return `true` instead of `false`.